# comparing multiple lines of a txt file to a single variable in python

Tags: python

I want to know how to compare multiple lines of a text file to a single variable. I have got it partially working but it only compares to last line of text file

```
def loginSetup():
    global loginSelector
    global accountInt
    loginSelector = int(input("Select Action:"))    
    
    if loginSelector == 1:
        #login
        print ("action complete")

    if loginSelector == 2:
        #sign up  
        accountInt = int(input("Input 4 Digit Pin:"))
        while (accountInt >= 9999 or accountInt <= 999):
            print("ERROR\nTry Again")
            accountInt = int(input("Input 4 Digit Pin:"))
        accountInt = str(accountInt)
        with open('Account.txt', 'r') as rf:
            for line in rf:
                if (line == str(accountInt)):
                    print("error")
        with open('Account.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.write('\n')
            f.write(accountInt)
            



while True: 
    loginSetup()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because rather than the standard way of writing a line of text followed by a newline, you're writing the newline first.  So the last line of the file doesn't have a trailing newline (and allows the comparison to succeed there).

In the loop, `line` will be some text with a newline at the end (for all but the last line), and `str(AccountInt)` will never have a newline.  So no match is possible.

You'll want to strip the newline from your string before comparing.

Comment: thanks that helps is there any way you could show me what that might look like in code thanks again

Comment: Besides writing the newline after your text, a simple change would be to compare against `line.rstrip()` rather than `line` inside the for loop.